# Insert query with Update

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

Table "Names":

```
ID     |   Name
---    |   ---
123    |  John
164    |  Peter
346    |  Mark
679    |  Bob
```

Table "Companies":

```
ID     |   Company
---    |   ---
111    |   XXX
666    |   YYY
777    |   ZZZ
```

Table "Table1":

```
ID     |   c1    |    c2    |    NameID    |    CompanyName
---    |   ---   |    ---   |    ------    |    -----------
1254   |    1    |     A    |     123      |       XXX
1548   |    1    |     A    |     123      |       YYY
2649   |    1    |     A    |     123      |       ZZZ
2687   |    3    |     B    |     164      |       ZZZ
2699   |    1    |     A    |     164      |       YYY
2700   |    4    |  (NULL)  |     346      |       XXX
2711   |    4    |  (NULL)  |     346      |       YYY
2900   |    4    |     A    |     679      |       YYY
```

I need to make an insert query such that records with same c1 and c2 (if c2 not null) or same c1 only (if c2 is null) are inserted to Table2 and updating the ID in Table2 to be the minimum ID from Table1.

The outcome should be like this:

Table "Table2":

```
ID     |   c1    |    c2    |    NameID    |    CompanyID
---    |   ---   |    ---   |    ------    |    -----------
1254   |    1    |     A    |     123      |       111
1254   |    1    |     A    |     123      |       666
1254   |    1    |     A    |     123      |       777
2687   |    3    |     B    |     164      |       777
2687   |    1    |     A    |     164      |       666
2700   |    4    |  (NULL)  |     346      |       111
2700   |    4    |  (NULL)  |     346      |       666
2900   |    4    |     A    |     679      |       666
```

Comment: as i can judge from the outcome, you only need to change CompanyName to CompanyID

Comment: I believe you want to create a table where you are going to store select query results, which is not really a good idea, simply provide a query whenever needed. Updating an ID is usually a bad idea also, you may break an integrity of your data.

Comment: @Ruli It's just that i need all the records to be inserted with minimum ID.

Comment: I got you, but I still think it's a bad idea to do so, why do you need to create such table? I believe there is better way to achieve what you need without creating rows with same ID in one table, but I still didn't understand why are you trying to achieve this.

Comment: @Ruli Well, after doing so, I need to delete all records from Table1 which their IDs are not available in Table2 (which means leaving only the minimum ID),In this way,Table2 will be a relational table having information needed(Name and company) and thus a person is unique in his ID and not his code. Hope this made it clear.

Comment: Is the 5th record in outcome correct? Should there be ID 1254? If yes, I edited my question. The result works for me

Comment: @JurijJazdanov Yes it is. It's the mimum id of 1-A > (c1-c2)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table2(ID, c1, c2, NameId, CompanyId)
SELECT 
    minTable.ID AS ID, 
    t1.c1 AS c1, 
    t1.c2 AS c2,
    t1.NameId AS NameId,
    c.ID AS CompanyId
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Companies c ON t1.CompanyName = c.Company
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        MIN(t1.ID) AS ID, 
        t1.c1 AS c1, 
        t1.c2 AS c2
    FROM   Table1 t1
    JOIN Companies c ON t1.CompanyName = c.Company
    GROUP BY c1, c2
) minTable ON t1.c1 = minTable.c1 AND (t1.c2 = minTable.c2 OR (t1.c2 IS NULL AND minTable.c2 IS NULL))
```

Comment: ID is different too .. which is the main case. I need the minumum ID based on c1 and c2